In python, if a list of numbers/objects is multimodal, how to get python output all those modes
Let's say a list of numbers in python is multi modal eg., it has 2 , 6 ,8 as equally most common in the list. Using statistics library only one mode is being displayed in output. How to get the output as all the modes.
As mentioned above, I want mutli modes to be displayed

What statistics library are you using? Please provide a [mcve].

Modes are pretty simple, you don't need a statistics package to get them.
test = [2, 6, 8, 1, 5, 2, 6, 8]
import collections
counts = collections.Counter(test)
mode_count = max(counts.values())
mode_count
# => 2
modes = [key for key,value in counts.items() if value == mode_count]
modes
# => [2, 6, 8]


If you want to use the statistics library, you can use the following code:
from statistics import multimode, mean
numbers = ['3', '3', '4', '4']
modes = multimode(numbers)
print(f"The modes are: {', '.join(modes)}")

I, however, would recommend using collections. You can do this like this:
from collections import Counter
numbers = [2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 5]
result_dict = Counter(numbers)
modes = [float(i) for i in result_dict.keys() if result_dict[i] == max(result_dict.values())]
print(f"The modes are: {', '.join(map(str, modes))}")

Collections will give whole numbers as a float while statistics will give whole numbers as an integer.

Why do you need to use map(int? multimode returns a list of integers.

The result should be [2, 5], but your code returns 3.5. Why are you calculating the mean of the multimode?
